# Lambda Parameter not in scope when using SimpleRepository Find

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have this simple little method that is trying to use the SimpleRepositry Find method in SubSonic 3.0.0.3.  When I make the call I get a invalid operation exception "Lambda Parameter not in scope", which added a touch of sadness to my coding afternoon.

```
public override IEnumerable<ICustomer> FindCustomers(string searchTerm)
{            
   return Repos.Find<Customer>(cust => cust.FirstNames.StartsWith(searchTerm)).ToArray();
}
```

Now, given how much fun SubSonic has been so far, I'm not going to give up without a fight, so does anybody out there have any advice?  I suspect that this is just a bug, but given that I've only been using SS a few days I'm not experienced enough to make that call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug based on Rob's answer to this question:

["Lambda Parameter not in scope" exception using SimpleRepository's Single method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186320/lambda-parameter-not-in-scope-exception-using-simplerepositorys-single-method)

Comment: Yes it does, but I don't see any bugs on github... so I guess I might raise it then.